# django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1242, 'Subquery returns more than 1 row')

Tags: python, django

Upon calling the `get_tag_posts` method of the Profile model, it is raising the following error:

- `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1242, 'Subquery returns more than 1 row')`

What about the query is causing this error and what correction should be made in order to resolve this it?

**authors/models.py**

```
class Profile(Model):
    user = OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=CASCADE)

    def get_tag_posts(self, order_by=None):
        tags = Tag.objects.filter(
            question__profile=self
        ).distinct()
        questions_with_tag = self.questions.filter(
            tags__name=OuterRef("name")).only('id')
        records = tags.annotate(
            times_posted=Count(Subquery(questions_with_tag)),
            avg_question_score=Avg("question__score", output_field=IntegerField())
        )
        if not order_by or order_by not in ['name', 'score']:
            order_by = "name"
        if order_by == "name":
            records = records.order_by(order_by)
        else:
            records = records.order_by("-avg_question_score")
        return {
            'records': records,
            'title': f"{tags.count()} Tags"
        }
```

**posts/models.py**

```
class Tag(Model):

    name = CharField(unique=True, max_length=25)


    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = "tag"


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f"/questions/posted/{self.name}"


class Post(Model):

    body = TextField()
    date = DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    comment = ForeignKey('Comment', on_delete=CASCADE, null=True)
    profile = ForeignKey(
        'authors.Profile', on_delete=SET_NULL, null=True,
        related_name='%(class)ss',
        related_query_name="%(class)s"
    )
    vote = GenericRelation(
        'Vote', related_query_name="%(class)s"
    )
    score = IntegerField(default=0)


    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        managed = True


class Question(Post):

    title = CharField(
        max_length=80, unique_for_date="date",
        help_text="Concisely state the problem you're having",
        error_messages={
            "max_length": "The title of your question is too long"
        }
    )
    tags = ManyToManyField(
        'Tag', related_name="questions", related_query_name="question"
    )
    views = IntegerField(default=0)
    visible = BooleanField(default=True)
    objects = Manager()
    postings = QuestionSearchManager()
    searches = QueryStringSearchManager()
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this, but give this a shot. Change `questions_with_tag` to: 
`questions_with_tag_count = self.questions.filter(myfilterhere).count()` and do
`times_posted=Subquery(questions_with_tag_count),`
...we know that `.count()` **always** returns a single item, so maybe it's that easy of a fix.